# How to set OnLongClickListener on only specific column in Listview But for ALL the rows

Tags: android, listview

I have an Android ListView view which consists of 1 textview and 2 edittexts in each row:

```
  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/topic_id"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight"1"
       />  

  <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/topic_name"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="2" 
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="15sp"
      />

  <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/topic_description"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="4" 
      android:textSize="15sp"
      />
```

I want the textview only to get setOnLongClickListener, so I
wrote the next loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<myListview.getCount();i++)
{
   //Here I get the (i) row in myListview
   View v = myListview.getChildAt(i);

   //Here I get the textView topic_id  in the (i) row
   TextView topic_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topic_id);

   //And here I put the setOnLongClickListener for this textView
   topic_id.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
         //do something...
         return true;
      }
   });      
}
```

The problem is that this loop fails:
After few iterations, the row

```
View v = myListview.getChildAt(i);
```

presents v as null becuase getChildAt(i) will not 
work for rows which can not been seen right now (rows you need to scroll
in the list for watching them).

If someone knows how to do it I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you using custom adapter for your `ListView`?

Comment: I'm using adapter which extends BaseAdapter.

Comment: As agamov mentioned in his answer, please do `TextView topic_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topic_id);

   topic_id.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()` inside your `getView()`

Comment: While you wrote your response, I was trying his answer and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely do this in your `ListAdapter`'s `getView()` method and NOT by manually traversing `ListView` child views.

Comment: Yep, you were right. Thank you. For any one who read this: I did what I wrote in the question but without the for loop. Inside getview() I got the textView and then I set onLongClickLister On this textView.